# Django orm filter is an element of dict

Tags: python, django, dictionary, orm

I'm trying to set a dict of filters for my ORM queryset.
here is my dict:

```
section = self.kwargs['section'] # hot or new or trending
threshold = {'hot': 'post_upvotes > 50', 'trending': 'post_upvotes__range=(20,50)', 'new': 'post_upvotes < 20'}
return Post.objects.filter(threshold[section])
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

threshold = {
    'hot': Q(post_upvotes__gt=50),
    'trending': Q(post_upvotes__range=(20,50)),
    'new': Q(post_upvotes__lt=20)
}

return Post.objects.filter(threshold[section])
```

Read more about Q objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects